# How to display twitter home_timeline with Oauth?

Tags: php, oauth, twitter

twitter API functions list please. I want to display twitter home_time using twitter tokens

Eg: get_accountVerify_credentials();

Comment: What did you try ? Can you post some code ? What is the problem exactly ? Do you get an error message ? *(Well, you need to tell us more -- and not just ask for a list of functions)*

Comment: I want to display home_timeline using tokens

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the Twitter API documentation?  I'm not sure what the specific question is here.

http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-API-Documentation

There are examples on the wiki for the OAuth part.  Note that the OAuth stuff is purely for authentication.  Once you have the `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret` following a user authenticating, you merely need to pass the OAuth parameters along with your request.  There are many libraries to do the hard work for you (twitter's wiki mentions some for you).

http://apiwiki.twitter.com/OAuth-Examples

Twitter's API is a clean, simple REST API.  There's nothing much to do other than access the defined URLs and interpret the XML returned.  Again, there are libraries for parsing XML.

Answer (score -2):

Use this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/home_timeline.xml/json");
```